# Rails sort by count and time of a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, join, voting

I'm using acts_as_votable for my activities model and I've been able to select only the activities that have votes on them with the following code:

```
@activities = Activity.select("activities.*, COUNT(votes.id)").joins(:votes).group("activities.id").order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(72)
```

But how do I select activities that only have for example greater than 3 votes and only the ones created within the last month?

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`having` was what I was looking for. So for example:

```
@activities = Activity.joins(:votes).group("activities.id").having("count(votes.id) >= ?", 1).order("created_at desc").where(:created_at => 6.months.ago..Time.zone.now.to_date).page(params[:page]).per_page(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

In example,

```
Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])
```

or

```
Activity.where("votes.id > ? and created_at > ?", 3, beginning_of_month*)
```

Also, "[Chapter 2: Conditionals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)" may be of use to you!

*http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/beginning_of_month

Comment: Thanks but if I use where like this it'll throw `SQLException: no such column: votes:` plus that code gives another error: `syntax error, unexpected ')'`